# How to import torchreid in google colab?

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install torchreid which is a library for person re-identification in PyTorch. I've followed the steps mentioned on the [git repository](https://github.com/nikunjmshah/Person-Tracking-and-Re-ID/tree/15382dbca167748fbd358289f8b820cf96e75b06/deep-reid) but is getting this error.

```
#conda install 
!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local python=3.6 ujson

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

!git clone https://github.com/KaiyangZhou/deep-person-reid.git

!cd deep-person-reid/
!conda create --name torchreid python=3.7
!conda activate torchreid
!pip install -r /content/deep-person-reid/requirements.txt
!conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch

import torchreid
```

error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4faf46a39b5d> in <module>()
----> 1 import torchreid

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchreid'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below command,

```
# install torchreid (don't need to re-build it if you modify the source code)
python setup.py develop
```

Answer (score -1):

First deactivate you created conda environment 'torchreid'. Activate it again and try to import.

> deactivate torchreid

> conda activate torchreid

Note: you are installing torchreid in a specifica conda environment, which in not accessible from outside of that environment.